# Implementing a Quick sort Algorithm C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement and construct a Quick Sort algorithm form scratch, I have been browsing different postings and this seems like a popular topic, I'm just not entirely sure how to interpret what other people have done with it to get mine working.

```
public static void QuickSort(int[] A)
    {
        int i, j, pivot,counter,temp;

        counter = 1;                                    //Sets Initial counter to allow loop to execute
        while (counter != 0)
        {   i = -1;                                     //Left bound
            j = 0;                                      //Right bound
            counter = 0;                                //Count of transpositions per cycle set to zero
            Random rand = new Random();
            pivot = rand.Next(0, A.Length - 1);         //Random Pivot Value Generated

            for (int x = 0; x < A.Length; x++)          //Executes contents for each item in the array
            {                                       
                if (A[pivot] > A[j])                    //Checks if pivot is greater than right bound
                {
                    i++;                                //left bound incremented
                    temp = A[j];                        
                    A[j] = A[i];                    
                    A[i] = temp;                        //swaps left and right bound values
                    j++;                                //Right bound Incremented
                    counter++;                          //Increments number of transpositions for this cycle.
                }
                else j++;                               //else right bound is icremented
            }
                                                        //Heres where it gets sketchy
            temp = A[i+1];                              
            A[i + 1] = A[pivot];                        //pivot value is placed in Index 1+ left bound

            for (int x =(i+2); x <A.Length; x++)        //Shifts the remaining values in the array from index of pivot (1+ left bound) over one position to the end of the array (not functional)
            {
                temp = A[x];
                A[x + 1] = temp;                                       
            }
        }          
    }
```

As you can see I've sort of hit a wall with the shifting portion of the algorithm, and I'm honestly not sure how to continue without just copying someone's solution from the web

Comment: your indexers are all over the place with some duplicating others and to compound the mistakes used in the wrong place.  Seems like you need a lot of practice in algorithms (let alone c#) - I'd suggest starting at the chapter on bench testing because your code is complete nonsense.

Comment: You need to go back and study how Quicksort works. In particular, you need to understand that it's a *divide and conquer* algorithm. Your attempted implementation doesn't divide, and thus its attempted conquest is thwarted. Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

First step -- Actually understand what is happening in a Quicksort...

**Basic Quicksort Algorithm**

- From your collection of items, select one (called the pivot). (How it is chosen is theoretically irrelevant but may matter on a practical level)
- Separate the items in your collection into two new collections: Items less than the pivot, and Items greater than the pivot.
- Sort the two new collections separately (how is irrelevant -- most implementations call themselves recursively).
- Join the now sorted lower collection, the pivot, and the sort upper collection.

Now, this particular implementation is a bit bizarre. It's trying to do it in place, which is OK, but it doesn't seem to ever move the pivot, which means it's going to be overwritten (and therefore change in the middle of the partitioning)

A few nit-picky things.

- Don't create a new `Random` object in the middle of the loop.  Create it once outside the loop, and reuse it.  There are several reason for this.  1) It takes a (relative) long time, and 2) it's seeded with the time in milleseconds, so two created within a millisecond of each other will create the same sequence -- here you'll always get the same pivot.
- Actually, it's best not to use a random pivot at all.   This was probably inspired by basic misunderstanding of the algorithm.  Originally, it was proposed that, since it didn't matter which item was picked as the pivot, you might as well pick the first item, because it was easiest. But then it was discovered that an already sorted collections have a worst-case time with that as the pivot.  So, naturally they went completely the other way and decided to go with a random pivot.  That's dumb.  For any given collection, there exists a pivot that cause a worst-case time.  By using a random pivot, you increase your chance of hitting it by accident.  The best choice: For an indexable collection (like an array), best to go with the item physically in the middle of the collection. It'll give you the best-case time for an already sorted collection, and it's worst-case is a pathological ordering that you're unlikely to hit upon.  For a non-indexable collection (like a linked-list -- betcha' didn't know you could Quicksort a linked list), you pretty much have to go with using the first item, so be careful when you use it.
- If the first time through the loop, a[0] is less than the pivot, `i` is equals to `j`, so you swap A[0] with itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `IComparer`.

> This interface is used in conjunction with the `Array.Sort` and
>   `Array.BinarySearch` methods. It provides a way to customize the sort
>   order of a collection. See the Compare method for notes on parameters
>   and return value. The default implementation of this interface is the
>   Comparer class. For the generic version of this interface, see
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<T>`.

```
public class Reverse : IComparer
{
    int IComparer.Compare(Object x, Object y) => 
         ((new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare( y, x ));  
}
```

The above method is an example, then you would:

```
IComparer reverse = new Reverse();
collection.Sort(reverse);
```

Simply pass your comparison to the `Sort` on the collection, it will perform and display reversed.  You can go even more in depth with greater control and actually sort based on specific model properties and etc.

I would look into `Sort` and the `IComparer` above.  More detail about `IComparer` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.compare(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The way he compares items is the least of his problems.